# VBA Running javascript from external URL

Tags: javascript, excel, vba

I have 0 experience with running javascript from excel through VBA.
As I have only minimal knowledge of js feel free to ask me anything that might be needed to solve my issue.

I would love to run a:

```
 navRightLeftCell(objEvent, tblBody, objEvent.shiftKey);
```

From page. That page contains multiple iform ( I am not sure if this is relevant). This JS can be found in "emxUIFreezePane.js". ( dont know if this is relevant either).
This js is run when i press "TAB" on keyboard - dont know if this is relevant either.

i have tried

```
 IE.document.parentWindow.execScript
```

However it did not work and I got such an error in Debugger:

```
 navRightLeftCell('9', tblBody, objEvent.shiftKey)
 'navRightLeftCell' is undefined
```

I have URL of the .js where "navRightLeftCell" can be found.
Is it possible to run scrip from external URL? And if yes - how? If not what other solution comes to your head?

Comment: What's an "iform"?